# mysqli_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result

Tags: php, mysql, sql

возникла некая ошибка:

### mysqli_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result

Пути решения которой неподвластны мне, прошу помощи у добродушных обитателей сие сайта.

```
 $link = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass);
 mysqli_select_db($link,$name);

 //получаем все таблицы
 if ($tables == '*') {
     $tables = array();
     $result = mysqli_query($link,'MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT');
     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
         $tables[] = $row[0];
     }
 } else {
     $tables = is_array($tables) ? $tables : explode(',',$tables);
 }
```

Comment: Данная ошибка в 99% случаев означает, что предыдущая команда вместо набора записей вернула false, что означает ошибку. Выводите сообщения об ошибках, а не игнорируйте их.

Comment: `print_r($result)` что там?

Comment: Dmitriy Saxarov - false

Answer (score 1):

Во первых "`MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT`" - это константа( это обозначает, что не требуется добавлять кавычки (").
Во вторых делайте проверку после каждого `mysqli_query`, если он возвращает false (в случае ошибки), тогда все дальше связано с ним не работает.
Напишите, что хотите сделать, или перейдите по [ссылке [EN]](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.store-result.php)